# Does changing github username effect pages?

Tags: javascript, html, git, github

If I change my github username to `new_username` will my github page projects be my new username?

Example: `https://old_username.github.io/project_name`

will become `https://new_username.github.io/project_name`,

and `https://old_username.github.io/`

will become `https://new_username.github.io/`.

Comment: I would assume so, yes. https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/changing-your-github-username#repository-references

Comment: Be mindful of redirects. It mentions that if someone claims your old username, any redirects to your new username may stop working. Update any links pointing to old_username.github.io as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your username changes your pages subdomain.
I changed my username and `https://old_name.github.io/project` became `https://new_name.github.io/project`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the *article*, mentioned in the comment section by [@evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75490034/does-changing-github-username-effect-pages/75490507#comment133192415_75490034), you can read more about it following the next [source](https://docs.github.com/ru/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/changing-your-github-username#about-username-changes):

> After changing your username, your old username becomes available for
> anyone else to claim.
>
> Most references to your repositories under the old username
> automatically change to the new username. However, some links to your
> profile won't automatically redirect.

Answer (score 0):

From the GitHub [Reference](https://docs.github.com/ru/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/changing-your-github-username#about-username-changes) page:

*After you change your username, GitHub will automatically redirect references to your repositories.*

Web links to your existing repositories will continue to work. This can take a few minutes to complete after you make the change.

Command line pushes from your local repository clones to the old remote tracking URLs will continue to work.

If the [**new owner of your old username**] creates a repository with the same name as your repository, that will override the redirect entry and your redirect will stop working. Because of this possibility, *we recommend you update all existing remote repository URLs after changing your username.*